# Why the definition of derivative is restricted to function with full domain $\Bbb R^n$?

Tags: derivatives, manifolds

The definition from the book "Calculus On Manifolds" for example is as follow.

The *derivative* of a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ at a point $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$, if it exists, is the  linear transformation $Df(p) \in L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ such that
$$
 \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\|f(p+h)-f(p)-Df(p)h\|}{\|h\|} = 0;
$$

Why we use $\mathbb{R}^n$ as domain and not a more general subset ?

Comment: The domain can be any reasonable subset.

Comment: @EthanBolker but it not what the definition say

Comment: @frhack Sometimes books aren't as precise / good / complete as expected

Comment: I suspect that often the formalism  $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is relaxed and it means
a function with domain  $\subseteq  \mathbb{R}^n$ ...

Comment: Suppose that the domain has $p$ as an isolated point. What would this definition mean? There are also issues with non uniqueness of the derivative even with nonisolated points. The most common assumption is that the domain is open.